# Calculate an unconditional probability given the conditional probability

Tags: probability

The random variable $Y$ in uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. The random variable $X$ (dependent on $Y$) has a conditioned - under a given $Y=y$ - the uniform distribution on $[0,y]$. Calculate $P(X<0.5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the law of total probability:
$$
P(X\in B) = \int_{0}^{1} P(X\in B|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy = \int_{0}^{1} P(X\in B|Y=y)dy = \\\int_{0}^{1}\int_Bf_{X|Y}(x|y)dxdy.
$$
So
$$
P(X<\frac{1}{2}) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\min\{\frac{1}{2},y\}}\frac{1}{y}dxdy = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{0}^{y}\frac{1}{y}dxdy + \int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{y}dxdy = \\\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: But how? As I do this, I obtain a nonsensical answer: $$P(X<0.5)=\int_0^1 \left( \int_0^{0.5} \frac{1}{y} 1_{[0,y]}(x)\,dx \right) dy = $$

Comment: What is the exact domain of $X$. And the conditional probability density function?

Comment: $$=\int_0^{0.5}\ldots dy+\int_{0.5}^{1}\ldots dy=$$

Comment: $$=\int_0^{0.5} \left(\int_0^1 \frac{1}{y} 1_{[x,1]}\,dy\right)dx=\int_0^{0.5}\left(\int_x^1\frac{1}{y}dy\right)dx=\int_0^{0.5}(\ln 1-\ln x)dx=-x(\ln x-1)|_{0}^{0.5}=-\frac{1}{2}\ln \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}.$$ Is it correct?

Comment: I am not sure, as I don't know what the pdf is of $X|Y$, but it looks right.

Comment: The uniform distribution on $[0,y]$. I've edited the topic.

Comment: I've edited mine. Your answer is correct.